# Controlling switch using java but not xml in Android

Tags: android, switch-statement

Is there a way that I can control the switch in the java source but not in the .xml ? I want the switch to be on/off depending on a preference I've saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the reference of Switch
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

```
Switch switch = (Switch) findViewById(switchId);
switch.setChecked(true) // set it on;
switch.setChecked(false) // set it off;
```

Please replace switchId with the id you defined in the xml.